# How to add pagination at top and bottom of the product page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, pagination

Please help on adding pagination at top and bottom of the product page in magento 2 .

Comment: Hi. You want to add pagination on PDP or PLP?

Comment: PLP where magento default pagination at bottom of page i want at top too.

Comment: @MuhammadHamza please find below share answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255304/52244 if it's **match your solution** please mark it's as **valid answer** and please do up vote so if others looking same kind of answer they can get quick response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put css in less file:

> `app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less`

```
.toolbar-products .pages {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: It good to get quick solution but that to be more valid, for general info :  Getting used to the **!important** declaration in CSS is very easy, but it is also a **bad habit for a web developer** since **it leads to missing or ignoring the real underlying issues in the HTML structure** and the corresponding CSS styles that should better be fixed in other ways. The !important rule also **makes it hard for the user to apply their own styles for better readability or accessibility while viewing your website**.  hope you take it as suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Goto your **Theme folder**  and open this below given file

if not exist please copy from your **Parent Theme** or from **Magento_Catalog** module.

if you using **LUMA copy** for your theme then this file will exist.

> app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\module\_toolbar.less

In this file under @media-common at last add give css

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    ...

    .toolbar-products {
        .pages {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

and clear `pub/static/frontend/*` folder and `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/*`

and deploy you will get output like below share screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi @kanhaiyal Thanks
i cant find directory module_toolbar.less can you help me to find that...

Comment: @MuhammadHamza please check updated answer it was editor mistake **/** was missed